# Crawling websites to extract email

Tags: java, web-crawler

I have a web crawler, that does not work properly. If I visit a page, such like http://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/contact_support/ then I want to extract the emails from this page. And furthermore, if there are references to other websites from canon ( and it is ) then my crawler shall visit all these pages to gather mails.

Unfortunately, my method "searchforWord" does not work, I never reach the if statement, I don't know why. Where is my mistake?

Here are my classes:

Spider.class

```
 public class Spider {


 private static final int MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH = 10;
    private Set<String> pagesVisited = new HashSet<String>();
    private List<String> pagesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();



    /**
     * Our main launching point for the Spider's functionality. Internally it creates spider legs
     * that make an HTTP request and parse the response (the web page).
     * 
     * @param url
     *            - The starting point of the spider
     * @param searchWord
     *            - The word or string that you are searching for
     */
    public void search(String url)
    {
        while(this.pagesVisited.size() < MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH)
        {
            String currentUrl;
            SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
            if(this.pagesToVisit.isEmpty())
            {
                currentUrl = url;
                this.pagesVisited.add(url);
            }
            else
            {
                currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
            }
            leg.crawl(currentUrl); // Lots of stuff happening here. Look at the crawl method in
                                   // SpiderLeg


            leg.searchForWord(currentUrl);



            this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
        }
        System.out.println("\n**Done** Visited " + this.pagesVisited.size() + " web page(s)");
    }


    /**
     * Returns the next URL to visit (in the order that they were found). We also do a check to make
     * sure this method doesn't return a URL that has already been visited.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private String nextUrl()
    {
        String nextUrl;
        do
        {
            nextUrl = this.pagesToVisit.remove(0);
        } while(this.pagesVisited.contains(nextUrl));
        this.pagesVisited.add(nextUrl);
        return nextUrl;
    }


  }
```

SpiderLeg.class

```
public class SpiderLeg
{
// We'll use a fake USER_AGENT so the web server thinks the robot is a 
 normal web browser.


      private static final String USER_AGENT =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, 
      like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1";
private List<String> links = new LinkedList<String>();
private Document htmlDocument;


/**
 * This performs all the work. It makes an HTTP request, checks the response, and then gathers
 * up all the links on the page. Perform a searchForWord after the successful crawl
 * 
 * @param url
 *            - The URL to visit
 * @return whether or not the crawl was successful
 */
public boolean crawl(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
        if(connection.response().statusCode() == 200) // 200 is the HTTP OK status code
                                                      // indicating that everything is great.
        {
           System.out.println("\n**Visiting** Received web page at " + url);
        }
        if(!connection.response().contentType().contains("text/html"))
        {
            System.out.println("**Failure** Retrieved something other than HTML");
            return false;
        }
        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        //System.out.println("Found (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links");
        for(Element link : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        // We were not successful in our HTTP request
        return false;
    }
}


public void searchForWord(String searchWord)
{


    Pattern pattern =
              Pattern.compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");

              Matcher matchs = pattern.matcher(searchWord);

              if (matchs.find()) {

                      System.out.println(searchWord.substring( matchs.start(), matchs.end()));


              }

              else
                  System.out.println("hdhdadsad");


}


public List<String> getLinks()
{
    return this.links;
}

}
```

SpiderTest.class

```
public class SpiderTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Spider spider = new Spider();
        spider.search("http://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/contact_support/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work"?

Comment: The if statement is never true, I dont know why.

Comment: I would re-write your question as "why isn't my regex working", and show what string you are trying to regex.  All the networking stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: I re-wrote my question. My method "searchforword" gets the currenturl as parameter.

Comment: The regex is for capturing email addresses right? so..unless you pass an email address as the "searchWord" it's not going to work. Currently you're passing in a URL.. Although I would expect "hdhdadsad"

Comment: @SpaceCowboy yes it is for capturing email adresses. What do you mean "currently you're passing in a URL"?

Comment: you expect java's regex pattern to know it's a url and retrieve the document from that location and search against that?

Comment: I am pretty new to this pattern stuff in java, so excuse me if I don't know specific properties. That's why  I am asking here

Comment: @Blnpwr  leg.searchForWord(currentUrl); you're passing in the currentURL as a parameter and then checking if that URL is an email address

Comment: @SpaceCowboy how can I solve this ?

Comment: @Blnpwr I'm not used to JSoup so I'm not expert...I wouldn't pass the URL to the searchForWord method. Instead I would let this method access the Document object and search for email addresses within within that.

Comment: Use a debugger. Put a breakpoint at the `if`. Look at the variable's value at that moment. Write a small test program to test your regex against this value. If you can't get it working, ask on SO - you'll have an MVCE then.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy THank you very much, I solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is valid.

see here http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97822

Use following code instead of  `if` to find all matches:

```
while (matchs.find()) {
    System.out.println(matchs.group());
}
```

Comment: regex is valid, i've tested it

Comment: The regex in general is valid, but I still can't reach my if statement.

Comment: The regex is fine, it's being run against the url of the page, not the contents.